# "TypeError" when importing colour-science module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, colors

Sorry if it might be question that is easy to answer, but I'm new to python and can't find the answer anywhere.

I'm trying to use the colour-science module and have installed it via pip (Windows 10 64bit with python 3.8.1). But as soon as I try to import the modul I get this error:

```
C:\Users\pc\Documents\Python Backup>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import colour

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
    from .notation import (MUNSELL_COLOURS, MUNSELL_VALUE_METHODS,
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\notation\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .munsell import MUNSELL_VALUE_METHODS
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\notation\munsell.py", line 134, in <module>
    from colour.volume import is_within_macadam_limits
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\volume\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .spectrum import (generate_pulse_waves, XYZ_outer_surface,
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\volume\spectrum.py", line 133, in <module>
    illuminant=sd_ones(STANDARD_OBSERVERS_CMFS[
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\colorimetry\generation.py", line 160, in sd_ones
    return sd_constant(1, shape)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\colorimetry\generation.py", line 94, in sd_constant
    wavelengths = shape.range(dtype)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\colour\colorimetry\spectrum.py", line 455, in range
    range_, current_interval = np.linspace(
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in linspace
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 119, in linspace
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

Has anyone any idea how/if I can fix that since the error seems to occure in one of the modul functions? That would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a known issue in the colour pkg 
https://github.com/colour-science/colour/pull/544

Comment: Oh, thanks. Good to know. Funny thing is, if I run the script in Spyder it works fine. But looks like they are going to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are known issues and should be fixed in a new package release soon.

Edit: 0.3.15 is up on Pypi and should be soon on Conda.